# CRON expression every minute between 13:30 to 20:00 Monday to Friday

Tags: cron, azure-functions

I am trying to create a CRON expression for Azure Function to run between 13:30 to 20:00 from Monday to Friday.
Following is my expression

```
0 30/1 13-20 * * 1-5
```

But it executes from 30-59 minutes past hour every hour between 13 to 20 hours.
I want it to start from 13:30 then every minute till 20:00. Can anybody guide me ion how to fix the problem?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a single expression.

Comment: This page also has examples for reference in the future. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do this in two separate lines, one for the 30 minutes between 13:30 - 13:59 and a second for every minute between 14:00 - 20:00.

`30-59  13   * * 1-5`

`*   14-19 * * 1-5`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it looks like that's the only way.